# mousedragged lags/skip when moving window/frame/program

Tags: java

I have my program undecorated, because of this I still want to move the program without a title bar. The code below for me does work, but it like lags or skips. It does work fine for a second the skips, works fine, skips... etc etc. Currently I have my if statement in the mousemoved off. Is there a better way to implement a mousedragged to move my window/frame/program?

```
addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {                  

            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(final MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        int posX=0;
                        int posY=0;
                        int posx=e.getLocationOnScreen().x;
                        int posy=e.getLocationOnScreen().y;
                        setLocation (posx - posX, posy - posY);
                    }};
                   SwingUtilities.invokeLater(runnable);                                       
                }


                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (SettingsIni.jmenuauto().equals("on")){
                        getJMenuBar().setVisible(e.getY() < 50);
                    }
                }           

            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try without the `invokeLater()`.

Moreover, I think `posX/Y` should be fields of the class and set in `mousePressed()` instead. As they stand here, they are not useful...

Comment: I have tried it without the invoke later and it is not any better. I found the invokelater in another post that recommended it.

Comment: Have you tried my other advice, about setting posX in mousePressed? Also, what version of Java are you using? On what platform are you testing this?

Comment: So the problem is somehow the table code that I am running. I recently made a new program, used the code adjustments you mentioned and it moves with no lag. I have a timer that updates in the program that is giving me trouble. My table then does like 30 updates every second, each update is pulling info from an ini file using ini4j, which also happens to be on a network. So your code won't save me there, I have other problems... :( Thanks for the help though! Atleast it works in my new program.